# Rotate point in coordinate system around abitrary point

Tags: rotation, coordinate-systems

I want to rotate a rectangle in a coordinate system. I already know how to rotate each point in it around the 0,0 position, but what I want is to rotate the rectangle around it's minimum x,y point (bottom left, so to speak). I already tried "normalizing" the points first (to 0,0) and then adding the offset again, but my math seems to be faulty.

Two images to clarify. The red circle is the point around which the points in the retangle are rotated. The min (=minimum) point around which to rotate is at 2,1 (bottom left of the dark green rectangle)

First image: What I already can do.

[image]

Second image: What I want to accomplish

[image]

Comment: If you mean "write all the points with respect to the bottom left corner of the image, as if it is the new oring, then apply rotation" with the word "normalizing" the method is correct. About your formulas: what is z, and where the "old" coordinates and where the "new" ones?  In your example you should write something like x' = -(y-y0) + x0 and y' = (x-x0) +y0 where (x0,y0) are the coordinates of your minimum point (2,1) and (x',y') are the coordinate that you are searching. But it is better to ask your math questions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/) rather then in this community

Comment: Thanks for your help. I originall used this with a 3-dimensional coordinate system with rotation around the y axis (which would be depth in this case), that's why I mistakenly used the z variable instead of y. I changed it in the first image. I will post this question in the Math section.